# How to make rigid bodies freeze?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. I'm just not sure how to describe it to someone else.

Here's what i'm trying to do:
I am creating a simulation with a cube, and a "bullet" going through it to make it fracture. It is a rigid body, but when I play the simulation, it just falls (not through the world, I have a plane that it stands on). I want it to start simulating when the bullet passes through it so it "fracture". Help will be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In the Physics tab under Rigid Body Dynamics select Enable Deactivation and then select Start Deactivated. The physics simulation will not start on the object until it is disturbed i.e. by your bullet hitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the cube to fall to bits on the plane then the plane needs to be a 'passive' object in the rigid body world so that it interacts with other objects.

If you want the cube to shatter in all directions you can turn gravity off but will still find pieces will pass through the plane if the plane is not part of the rigid body world.

Once everything is included in the rigid body world, you will then have to adjust parameters like collision margin and solver steps/iterations to make the pieces fall naturally on the plane and not penetrate it.